# Imblearn Pipeline resulting in poor metrics

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, imblearn

I am working on an imbalanced dataset which is created using the below code

```
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=2, n_redundant=0, n_clusters_per_class=1,
                            weights=[0.99], flip_y=0, random_state=1)
```

I tried getting rid of the imbalance using SMOTE oversampling and then tried fitting a ML model. This was done using the normal method and then by creating a pipeline.

**Normal method**

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

oversampled_data = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.5)
X_over, y_over = oversampled_data.fit_resample(X, y)

logistic = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')

scoring = ['accuracy', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1']
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)

# evaluating the model
scores = cross_validate(logistic, X_over, y_over, scoring=scoring, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1,  return_train_score=True)

print('Accuracy: {:.2f}, Precison: {:.2f}, Recall: {:.2f} F1: {:.2f}'.format(np.mean(scores['test_accuracy']), np.mean(scores['test_precision']), np.mean(scores['test_recall']), np.mean(scores['test_f1'])))
```

Output - Accuracy: 0.93, **Precison: 0.92**, Recall: 0.86, **F1: 0.89**

**Pipeline**

```
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline, Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

oversampled_data = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.5)

pipeline = Pipeline([('smote', oversampled_data), ('model', LogisticRegression())])

# pipeline = make_pipeline(oversampled_data, logistic)

scoring = ['accuracy', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1']
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)

# evaluating the model
scores = cross_validate(pipeline, X, y, scoring=scoring, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1,  return_train_score=True)

print('Accuracy: {:.2f}, Precison: {:.2f}, Recall: {:.2f}, F1: {:.2f}'.format(np.mean(scores['test_accuracy']), np.mean(scores['test_precision']), np.mean(scores['test_recall']), np.mean(scores['test_f1'])))
```

Output - Accuracy: 0.96, **Precison: 0.19**, Recall: 0.84, **F1: 0.31**

What am I doing wrong when using a Pipeline, why is the Precision and F1 score so poor when using a pipeline?

Comment: Maybe pipeline does not call fit_resample method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first approach, you create the synthetic examples **before** splitting the training and test sets, whereas in the second you do it **after** splitting.

The former approach adds synthetic datapoints to the test set, but the latter does not.  Furthermore, the former approach produces inflated scores from data leakage: it adds the synthetic test samples based (in part) on some datapoints from the training dataset.  See e.g.

- [Train/Test Split after perform SMOTE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/15630/55122)
- [Why did sampling boost the performance of my model?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/60764/55122)
- [Testing Classification on Oversampled Imbalance Data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/60180/232706)
- [Why you shouldn't upsample before cross validation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/82073/43000)